# Why is http.post not an async function

Tags: http, dart

I'm working on an application in dart. I use the http package.
I copied the example code from the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/http):

```
var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/whatsit/create');
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```

And get this error:

```
Error: The await expression can only be used in an async function.
```

I have no idea why this doesn't work. Its their own example.

Comment: Is the function which that code is contained in declared as async? Please see the example in the [Retrying requests](https://pub.dev/packages/http#retrying-requests) section on the page you linked to.

Comment: It was not, and that was the problem. Thanks or your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure your code is written inside a Future function like so:

```dart
void yourFunction() async {
  var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/whatsit/create');
  var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
  print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${response.body}');
}
```

Or if you can't do that, use `.then()` syntax

```dart
var url = Uri.parse('https://example.com/whatsit/create');
http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'}).then((response) {
   print('Response status: ${response?.statusCode}');
   print('Response body: ${response?.body}');
});
```